# Remove Discount Coupon from Magento ver 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

Does anyone know how i can disable/remove the Discount Coupon from Magento Shopping Cart Page v 1.9 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

In your theme's local.xml add the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layout>
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <remove name="checkout.cart.coupon"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks - Qtn, where is this XML file ?

Comment: you are using some theme.so in your theme's layout directorty create local.xml file and paste this code.
Tell me your theme name.

Comment: Thanks.  Would that be tempmela.xml in /app/design/frontend/default/MAG090172/layout

Comment: Template is Mega Shop

Comment: create local.xml /app/design/frontend/default/MAG090172/layout/local.xml and paste the code in it.

Comment: Hi - i have created a "executable" local.xml file in folder /app/design/frontend/default/MAG090172/layout  >>>>> with your code, but Block is NOT removed ?!   Even after clearing Mag Cache & Browser Cache .. pl help

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following code from  /app/design/frontend/your_package/yourtheme/layout/checkout.xml

```
  <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response, but checkout.xml is missing from the folder: public_html/app/design/frontend/default/MAG090172/layout

Comment: Copy checkout.xml from the base section, past it from your theme layout folder and edit the file.

Answer (score 1):

How to remove discount code block from magento cart

In order to remove the discount code block you have to open the checkout.xml file which is located in/app/design/frontend/default/[your_theme]/layout/checkout.xml.

If there is no such file, copy it from /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml to your theme and…

Remove block

Open the file and delete the following code:

```
<block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
```

If you want to delete the ESTIMATE SHIPPING AND TAX block, remove the following code from the same file. The code should be just after the previeous line.

```
<block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>
```

That’s all. Do not forget to refresh the cache.

Answer (score 0):

The changes in layout.xml is not shown untill you delete existing content an paste the layout.xml code and refresh cache